# e.stopPropagation does not work as expected in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following table:

```js
$("body").on('click', ".application-checkbox", function (e) {
      alert('checkbox');
      e.stopPropagation();
  });

  $('body').on('click', "tr", function (e) {
      alert('row');
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table> 
 <tr>
     <td>
         <div class="ckbox">
           <input type="checkbox" class="application-checkbox" id="checkbox">
           <label for="checkbox">label</label>
         </div>
      </td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

When I click on the checbox, both "row" and "checkbox" is printed out. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Both events are on the `<body>`. You would probably need to use `.stopImmediatePropagation()`, but even that may not work since the two events are bound to the same parent element.

Comment: Is there a reason you've bound them to the body? If not then binding to the actual element would solve the issue

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol: I have copied this: https://jsbin.com/icoxak/5/edit?html,js,output

Comment: also, please don't include your Razor. Just include raw HTML in your questions

Comment: remove `alert('checkbox');` and change it to `console.log('checkbox clicked');`

Comment: @Liam: I have followed this: https://jsbin.com/icoxak/5/edit?html,js,output

Comment: @Bryan  are you generating this table using jQuery? (dynamic table generation without page refresh)? If no, then why binding event on `body`?

Comment: @AlivetoDie: No, i'm not generating this with jquery. I just did because I have tried everything else. I have followed this: https://jsbin.com/icoxak/5/edit?html,js,output, and that code work in jsbin, but not mine.

Comment: No, only checkbox is printed out and your work is correct http://jsfiddle.net/xmcewhpk/

Comment: @Bryan  please add rendered HTML of your table in your question. Will be easy to give you answer

Comment: @Mohammad: Hm, does not work in my code..

Comment: https://jsbin.com/bipiqikewe/edit?html,js,output I've updated you code. Added checkbox and label. Here if you click on checkbox icon then it works properly. But if you click on label then it will call event on `tr` first and then `checkbox`.

Comment: So your saying you've blindly followed a jsbin but don't know what your doing? Maybe read the documentation? [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: @Liam: It works in Jsbin, but not in my application. So probably something wrong with my HTML.

Comment: Have you any error in console?

Comment: I've updated your question to include a working example, which does work. So your question does not include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your problem so cannot be answered.

Answer (score 1):

Both event handlers are attached to the `body` element. And the docs for [event.stopPropagation()](https://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/) say:

> Note that this will not prevent other handlers on the **same** element from running.

As of that `stopPropagation` does not prevent the handlers on the same element to be executed, it jutd prevets further propagation to other elements.

If even all other event handlers on the same element should not be executed anymore then you need 
[event.stopImmediatePropagation()](https://api.jquery.com/event.stopimmediatepropagation/):

> Description: Keeps the rest of the handlers from being executed and prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree.

```js
$("body").on('click', ".application-checkbox", function(e) {
  alert('checkbox');
  e.stopImmediatePropagation();
});

$('body').on('click', "tr", function(e) {
  alert('row');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div class="ckbox">
        <input type="checkbox" class="application-checkbox" id="checkbox">
        <label for="checkbox">label</label>
      </div>
    </td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

But the problem with that approach is that callback are called in order they are attached, so if the callback for `tr` was attached before the one of `.application-checkbox` it won't work.

So you need to either fix that or you need to attach the event listeners to differnt levels of the DOM:

```js
$("tbody").on('click', ".application-checkbox", function(e) {
  alert('checkbox');
  e.stopPropagation();
});

$('table').on('click', "tr", function(e) {
  alert('row');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div class="ckbox">
          <input type="checkbox" class="application-checkbox" id="checkbox">
          <label for="checkbox">label</label>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: @Bryan then the event handler for `tr` was attached before the one of `.application-checkbox` in your application.

Comment: The problem Is the div surrounding the checkbox. If I remove <div class="ckbox"></div>, it works...

Comment: @Bryan Then you have you have something else in your code that you don't show that has this effect. Based on the given code removing `<div class="ckbox">` must not change anything.